# How to find the radius of convergence of series solution of an ODE?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Recently, I watched a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lHAMZWDQHI which taught me how to find the radius of convergence of power series solution of an ODE. For example, if we want to find the radius of convergence of power series solution $\displaystyle y=\sum \limits _{i=0}^\infty c_n(x-1)^n$ of ODE $(x^2+2x+5)y''+xy'+y=0$, just finding the roots of $x^2+2x+5$ then computing the minimum distance between $1$ and one of the roots. Generally, we have an ODE as follows:$$y^{(n)}+p_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}+\cdots +p_1(x)y'+p_0(x)y=0,$$where $p_i(x)$ is analytic in the complex plane except for some poles, and $\rho _1,\rho _2,\ldots ,\rho _k$ are regular singular points. Assume $\displaystyle y(x)=\sum c_kx^n$ is a nonzero formal power series solution. Is it true that the radius of convergence of $y(x)$ equals $\displaystyle d=\min \limits _{1\leq i\leq k}\rho _i$? Is it possible that there exists $|z_0|>d$ making $y(z_0)$ converge?

Thanks very much for your precious help.

Comment: "where $p_i(x)$ is analytic in the complex plain except some poles" FYI, such a function is called "meromorphic". Also I think that should be $\min \{|\rho_k|\}$.

Comment: You are right. I did not write "meromorphic" because I want to express more simple and obvious... So, if it is possible that there exists $|z_0|>\min\{\rho_k\}$ making the power series $y(z_0)$ convergence?

Comment: My point is that complex numbers aren't ordered, so you can't take their minimum. You can take the minimum of their magnitudes though. Or are the $\rho_i$ intended to all be real?

Comment: I have corrected. It should be the norm of $\rho_i$

Answer (score 2):

The radius of convergence is **at least** $d=\min_{1\leq i\leq k}\{|\rho_k|\}$.  In general, ODEs have infinitely many solutions.  Typically (whatever that means) almost all of the solutions have that exact radius of convergence, but there is one (or more) solution with larger radius of convergence.

I like the presentation of this in the textbook

*Coddington, Earl A.*, An introduction to ordinary differential equations, Englewood Cliffs, N.J.: Prentice-Hall, Inc. XI, 292 p. (1961). [ZBL0123.27301](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0123.27301).

---

Example.  Differential equation
$$
y''(x) + \frac{1}{x-1}\,y'(x) - \frac{1}{x-1}\,y(x) = 0
$$
has general solution
$$
y(x) = A(x-1) + \frac{B}{x-1}
\tag1$$
where $A,B$ are two arbitrary constants.
Consider the series expansion for $(1)$ at $x=0$,
$$
y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k
\tag2$$
What is its radius of convergence?

If $B \ne 0$, then $(1)$ has a pole at $x=1$, so $(2)$ has radius of convergence $1$.  But if $B = 0$, then $(1)$ is a polynomial $A(x-1)$, so $(2)$ has infinite radius of convergence.

Comment: Do you mean the radius of convergence of solution $y(x)$ may be larger than $d$?

Answer (score 1):

There can be (isolated) solutions that have a larger radius of convergence, most trivially the zero solution.

However, a basic fact about power series is that if it converges for $z=z_0$, then it also converges for all $|z|<|z_0|$, or in other words, the radius of convergence is $|z_0|$ or larger. So no, the scenario of your question is not possible.

Comment: Forgive I don't quite follow. Do you mean the radius of convergence of solution $y(x)$ may be larger than $d$?

Comment: Yes, of some select solutions the radius may be larger. $d$ is only a lower bound, all solutions converge inside this radius. For instance an equation might have basis solutions $x$ and $\frac1{1-x}$, so that $d=1$ but the first solution obviously exists on all of $\Bbb R$